# Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

i am getting below error while i tried to run cocos2dx proj in eclipse:

```
Cocos2dxActivity cannot be resolved to a type   ApplicationDemo.java    
Cocos2dxEditText cannot be resolved to a type   ApplicationDemo.java    
Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView cannot be resolved to a type  ApplicationDemo.java
```

am i missing any lib?

Comment: Maybe this is import problem ...try pressing ctrl +shift + o

Comment: which cocos2d-x you trying to use ? if its the latest one 2.0.3 ?

Answer (score 7):

I was having this problem and it seemed that with the latest cocos2d-x the java build path is missing.

In Eclipse right click the project. Click on BuildPath/Linksource.

In the linked folder location put in the directory of the cocos2d java src

i.e.

> /Users/XXX/lib/cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.3/cocos2dx/platform/android/java/src

I named the src cocos2d

Answer (score 3):

In cocos2d-x 2.0.3 ...Cocos2d-x Lib java files has been considered as a different project only So import that project in the eclipse

Lets make it Simple

First Import the project in eclipse from this path - cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.3/cocos2dx/platform/android/java
You will see libcocos2dx project in eclipse ...Keep this project open always otherwise your projects will give error on the syntax of library

Run create-android-project

Now Import the project which you have created and just Run (If you know the concept of isLibrary then that's how they are maintaining it now ..)

Also additional information to run build-native.sh from eclipse only , Right Click Project ->C/C++ Build Uncheck Use Default Build COmmand and add following bash ${workspace_loc:/YourProjName}/build_native.sh NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1

Good Luck ..If any question please feel free to ask

Comment: What do you mean "keep this project open always"? Is it enough just import the cocos2d-x-2.0.3?